# What is the proper approach to implement `type Option<A> = None | Some<A>` without an error: Type alias 'Option' circularly references itself

Tags: typescript

I try to implement Option/Maybe type with self map method in the instanced object.

To do that, firstly implementing the internal definition of `none` and `some` with the proper types, then outside definition as `None` and `Some` then finally, `type Option<A> = None | Some<A>;`

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.2.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGAKdBKVA+GA3gFAwwD0ZAtNTbXfQ43SeWRgIYyX7w7cyd+8FlACeABwCmMcQEspqGAB4AggBoYAIVwtS6AGYAuDsZU4U+Tefzp2p61oDcLUJFhypxj9LT68A-31bLGdSCiYIyMiRCWkwcB9CXRgAW3ZxY1UNbQNjW3t-K394sEkWAF9QmFdoGBLJY3rFYlJSNIyYPws6hIrnGIUIEBTE1Vx8mDN-FtaAN3YAGwBXBsm1ZPbM9S1x5NIoAAtZCFN11tajE0mHTWSbvpdwWqGR4xfE4P90GdJ55dX2GdWptOkswMAoLJwBhDscNPocAQYAAnSRQJbIsAyeSSAxYdCwiAhGDlCohEgsVHozGEHqlDQwd4k5zlfHk8JRTlcyhEIhiBQAeXEkPAY0UADkEjAAD4wADKw0kY36-OkktKiiFIrASlKs0kyNwzlV8sVijGEym3S1UJ1KiNvJqsHVqxdigQiAAdPVnE7Ta9-YkPZ73v1JAAPcQgZGwJEwF0MhUjElAA)

```
const obj = (() => {
  //-----------------------------------------
  // (a -> b) -> a -> b
  type pipe = <A, B>
    (f: (a: A) => B) => (a: A) => B;
  const pipe: pipe = f => a => f(a);
  //-----------------------------------------
  type none = {
    map: <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => none
  };
  const none: none = {
    map: f => none
  };
  type some = <A>(a: A) => {
    value: A,
    map: <A, B>(
      this: A,
      f: (a: A) => B
    ) => B
  };
  const some: some = (a) => ({
    value: a,
    map: function (this, f) { return pipe(f)(this); }
  });
  return { none,  some };
})();
//-----------------------------------------
type Option<A> = None | Some<A>
type None = Option<never>;
type Some<A> = (a: A) => Option<A>;
const None: None = obj.none;
const Some: Some = obj.some;
export {  None,  Some }
```

So far, I simply have done this, but the errors are:

[image]

```
type Option<A> = any
Type alias 'Option' circularly references itself.(2456)
```

Surely, I understand what it suggests, but in TypeScript, it sometimes allow circular type definition, and either way, whatever the reason, I would like to know what is the typical approach or work-around to implement this pattern concisely.

Please advise.

Comment: You can have a recursive type but it has to change in each iteration somehow, like `type A = { prop: A }` works because you can lazily evaluate it. But you are basically doing `type A<T> = A<T> | A<never>`, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @AlexWayne I see, thanks for your insight. It help me understand better!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're actually thinking a bit *too* functionally on this one. Speaking as a Haskell programmer, it's a good mindset, but you're in Typescript right now, so we need to think with classes.

```
class None {

  constructor() {}

  map(f: (a: never) => unknown): None {
    return new None();
  }

}

class Some<T> {
  readonly value: T;

  constructor(value: T) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  map<S>(f: (a: T) => S): Some<S> {
    return new Some(f(this.value));
  }

}

type Option<T> = None | Some<T>;

const myFirstOption: Option<number> = new Some(1);
const mySecondOption: Option<number> = myFirstOption.map((x) => x + 1);
console.log(mySecondOption);

const myNone: Option<number> = new None();
const myOtherNone: Option<number> = myNone.map((x) => x + 1);
console.log(myOtherNone);
```

Union types in Typescript will infer the appropriate type for common methods, so `Option<T>` will see that `None` defines a `map` which takes `(a: never) => unknown` and `Some<T>` defines `map` which takes `(a: T) => S`, so it'll combine the two.

I declared `None.map` to take a function of type `(a: never) => unknown`, since `never` is the bottom type in Typescript and `unknown` is the closest thing we have to a top type, so `(a: never) => unknown` is a valid supertype of all one-argument functions, i.e. `None.map` can be called with *any* single-argument function.

---

As suggested in the comments, here's the same code using `interface` and tag fields rather than ES classes.

```
interface None {
  _tag: "None";
}

interface Some<T> {
  _tag: "Some";
  readonly value: T;
}

type Option<T> = None | Some<T>;

function none(): None {
  return { _tag: "None" };
}

function some<T>(value: T): Some<T> {
  return { _tag: "Some", value };
}

function map<T, S>(f: (a: T) => S, opt: Option<T>): Option<S> {
  if (opt._tag === "None") {
    return opt;
  } else {
    return some(f(opt.value));
  }
}

const myFirstOption: Option<number> = some(1);
const mySecondOption: Option<number> = map((x: number) => x + 1, myFirstOption);
console.log(mySecondOption);

const myNone: Option<number> = none();
const myOtherNone: Option<number> = map((x: number) => x + 1, myNone);
console.log(myOtherNone);
```

`type` can be used to emulate `interface`, so we could've replaced those top two definitions with

```
type None = {
  _tag: "None";
}

type Some<T> = {
  _tag: "Some";
  readonly value: T;
}
```

and gotten the exact same result.

Comment: Thanks, it's true I'm a functional programmer and do Haskell, but I'm afraid to say it's not true there is no approach such as too functional, and Class is absolutely unnecessary to do in TypeScript. In fact, fp-ts does this without any classes https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/Option.ts and I try ti re-produce in my way, but failed. So This is a good subject how to type this thing in TypeScript, I thought,

Comment: It looks like they do basically what I do but they use `interface` instead of `class`. So whereas my `Some` would be constructed with `new Some(blah)`, theirs would be constructed with `{ _tag: "Some", value: blah }`, i.e. an ordinary Javascript object with a hidden tag field.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your further insight, and in fact, I would like to understand what you suggest. Actually, I wonder how `interface` instead of the usage of `type` can solve the problem. IMO, using `interface` manner is better than `class`. Could you please re-write with `interface` without `classes` in my code context, if it's possible or it's not that hard for you. Appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, it's no trouble at all. Check out my edit and see if that's what you're looking for!

Comment: Yes, I added it below the original solution. I don't want to delete the original as it might be useful to someone. The `interface` / `type` based solution is below my original answer.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment is due to malfunction of reload. Thanks for your extra code!! This really helps me understand how this thing work, and perhaps I may have an extra comment of question studying your code. I really really appreciated! Silvio Mayolo

Comment: An additional suggestion when doing this with TS: There are cases where multiple data types may have a `None` variant. Since TS is structurally typed, `Option::None` and `SomeOtherType::None` would be structurally identical. I'd suggest name spacing the tag: `{_tag: "Option::None" }` or adding another property tagging the data type so that your functions don't incorrectly accept a variant from a different data type.